# How to capture negative numbers in SpecFlow

Tags: c#, specflow, gherkin

Using SpecFlow, I have this scenario:

```
Scenario: Amount is not negative
  Given a Validator
  Given a TestData
    And MinimumAmount is -0.01
  When when validator is invoked
  Then validator sets validation error
```

SpecFlow generated the following binding for the MinimumAmount:

```
[Given]
public void Given_MinimumAmount_is_P0(decimal p0)
{
 ....
}
```

But when executed, the value passed to the step is `0.01` and not `-0.01`.

How do I set this, so it captures the minus sign?

Comment: "Amount is not negative" is this correct?

Comment: yes, I want to test validator, which ensures that the amount is not negative. For this, I need to pass negative and see it failing.

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out. Looks like that the "default" behavior is wrong, but after I set proper text for the Give attribute, it started working.

I changed the step definition to:

```
[Given(@"MinimumAmount is (.*)")]
public void Given_MinimumAmount_is_P0(decimal p0)
{
 ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[PR submitted](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/pull/623) to fix this issue just now. Hopefully this will make the 2.1 release, it seems like a simple fix. Anything you can do to verify the fix once its been merged in would be appreciated